# Can we use client credentials flow on regular Azure users?

Tags: azure

We would like to use Azure client credentials flow to do authentication for our service accounts. The thing is our service accounts are just regular users in Azure AD. They are not registered apps. The way our company sets up Azure makes it very heavy to register apps, so we would like to avoid it. So the question is, can we use client credentials flow for regular users in Azure? We need this as in our CI/CD we cannot popup a browser and let users do device-based authentication. We need the user to be able to authenticate in an automated way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use client credentials flow where an Azure AD user is involved in the authentication flow.

[Micrsofot Documentation - client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow)

> This type of grant is commonly used for server-to-server interactions that must run in the background, **without immediate interaction with a user**.

But you can use one of the following supported authentication flow where a user is involved;

1. [Micrsofot Documentation - authorization code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow)
2. [Micrsofot Documentation - implicit grant flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow)
3. [Micrsofot Documentation - device authorization grant flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-device-code)

Device authorization grant flow might work in your case?

Comment: It won't. The reason is we need to authenticate these service accounts in our build CI/CD pipeline. So we need an automated way to authenticate them. The thing here is our company Azure set up makes it very cumbersome to register an app. Even our service accounts are just Azure AD users.

Comment: Why it won't? You can automate your build CI/CD pipeline with one of the above auth flow using Azure CLI, Powershell or REST API.

Comment: You are right. We can use those other flows to do automated authentication. Closing the question.